# Whatever I do, I keep getting -> Error in file(file, "rt")

Tags: r, file, path, directory

I've researched this error extensively and tried everything that seemed relevant, can't seem to wrap my head around this while it seems fairly easy :-s

Location "pollutantmean.R"

```
> source('~/Desktop/R Projects/assigment1/pollutantmean.R')
```

The script 'pollutantmean.R' looks like this

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){   
    filesList <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)[id]  
    dat <- data.frame()  
    for (i in seq_along(id)) {    
        dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(filesList[i]))  
    }  
    mean(dat[, pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)  }
```

My working directory is

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/nickpoels/Desktop/R Projects/assigment1"
```

My working directory contains

```
> dir()
[1] "pollutantmean.R"         "rprog-data-specdata.zip" "specdata"
```

"specdata" contains all the .csv-files

Now when I call my function, this is what I keep getting

```
> pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 70:72)

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection 
In addition: Warning message:In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I suggest you add `browser()` early in your function and trace what is going on. I don't think there's much we can do without more insight.

Comment: one question - what operating system are you using? the path to your working directory looks like a windows path. But the "~" in your path to the filename will only work in linux.

Comment: or on a mac (which is also unix-like)

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need a `full.names=TRUE` argument in your `list.files` in `pollutantmean()`. So that the entire path will be retrieved by `list.files` and it should work whether you provide a relative or absolute path.